# How to split a string into individual characters

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to build a script that will print on screen each char from the given string.

Lets say I call the script `show_chars` then

```
./show_chars bkob bk.is
```

will give me

```
b
k
o
b

b
k
.
i
s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fold` for this:

```
s='bkob bk.is'
fold -w1 <<< "$s"
b
k
o
b

b
k
.
i
s
```

As per `man fold`:

```
  -w, --width=WIDTH
          use WIDTH columns instead of 80
```

Comment: there is a problem that i want it to be a script in a file (#!/bin/bash..)

how can i get all of as one variable ( $1 ) to use your code?

Comment: Inside script just use `fold -w1 <<< "$@"`

Answer (score 3):

or

```
echo $1 | grep -o .
```

works also

Comment: sorry but not wroking

Comment: Dont' forget . at the end

Comment: What is not working ? You just have to put that line in your script